# how can I reference a method from the same component in the data of the component vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have the following component

```
<template>
   <li v-for="(item, i) in this.menu" :key="i" @click="item.action()"> //trying to call the method in the component
      {{menu.title}}
   <li>
</template>
<script>
export default {
        data: () => ({
            menu: [
                {title: 'Start Preparing', action: this.startPrepare}, //how do I reference the method here?
                {title: 'Cancel Order'},
            ],
        }),

        methods: {
            startPrepare: function (orderId) {
                console.log("start")
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

As you can see in the commented sections, I have a `menu` in the data section, it has a `title` and `action` properties in it. So in the template, I want to invoke whatever function we have specified when someone clicks on that particular item.

So how do I refer a method in the same component in the data section of that component? as of now, I am getting start prepare is `undefined` error.

Let me know if any further clarifications are needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here I think is that you're using an arrow function for your `data`, which can't be bound to the Vue instance. You need to use a normal function instead ..

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      menu: [{
          title: 'Start Preparing',
          action: this.startPrepare
        }, //how do I reference the method here?
        {
          title: 'Cancel Order'
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    startPrepare: function(orderId) {
      console.log("start")
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<template>
    <li v-for="(item, i) in this.menu" :key="i" @click="item.action()"> //trying to call the method in the component
        {{menu.title}}
    <li>
</template>
```

Comment: This is apter I think, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the method name as a string like action value and in the template access it like `@click="handleAction(item.action)"`:

```
<template>
   <li v-for="(item, i) in menu" :key="i" @click="handleAction(item.action)">
      {{menu.title}}
   <li>
</template>
<script>
export default {
        data: () => ({
            menu: [
                {title: 'Start Preparing', action:'startPrepare'}, //how do I reference the method here?
                {title: 'Cancel Order'},
            ],
        }),

        methods: {
          handleAction(actionName){
          this[actionName]();
           }
            startPrepare: function (orderId) {
                console.log("start")
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: `error in v-on handler: "TypeError: [item.action] is not a function"`

Comment: I kind of tried to do this, but I was getting the same error like I commented above

Comment: Thank you, It did worked. I will use this for now. But I feel like this is a hack. Let me know if any native way of doing this thing :)

Comment: you're welcome, this not a hack, since JS is more flexible and let you access field in different ways